# Spring Boot NoOp Fallback Bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations

Following code works like expected.

When a `MailSender` is available in the context an `EmailService` is created.
When no `MailSender` is available the `NoopEmailSender` is created.

From my understanding Spring Boot prefers the method with the most parameters when they have the same names. Unfortunately I can not find this behavior described somewhere in the documentation or JavaDoc.

My issue is that I'm not sure if the code works just because of "luck"/"random" or this behavior is intended.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MailConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public EmailSender emailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
        return new EmailService(mailSender);
    }

    @Bean
    public EmailSender emailSender() {
        log.info("Email sending is not configured.");
        return new NoopEmailSender();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The behavior wasn't intended and works because of method overloading (I guess). You are probably better of, as you are using Spring Boot, to annotate the methods with conditional rule. `@ConditionalOnBean(MailSender.class)` and the other with the opposite. That way it is documenten and made explicit.